# Poor MD3000i read performance (for one controller, but not the other)

Tags: performance, iscsi, dell-powervault

We have an MD3000i array accessed by three separate servers (all blade servers accessing through chassis nic's). Controller 1 (both Ports 0 and 1) are linked to Server A. Servers B and C (both with substantially less activity than Server A) are linked to Controller 0 (Ports 0 and 1). Server A is on a separate VLAN (connected to the MD3000i through a switch on the back of the blade chassis), and Servers B and C are on their own VLAN (also connected to the MD3000i through a switch on the back of the blade chassis).

The problem we are running into is that Server A has decidedly better read throughput from the MD3000i. For instance, when looking at backup jobs run through that server, the job rate is roughly 3,000MB/min. However, when looking at backup jobs run through Servers B or C, jobs rates are as low as 200MB/min.

If I view the iSCSI MAC transmit statistics through the MDSM, there are very different readings between controllers (aside from overall volume):

```
Mac transmit statistics

MAC transmit legend

F = Frame Count
B = Byte Count
MF = Multicast Frame Count
BF = Broadcast Frame Count
PF = Pause Frame Count
CF = Control Frame Count
FDF = Frame Deferral Count
FED = Frame Excess Deferral Count
FLC = Frame Late Collisions Count
FA = Frame Abort Count
FSC = Frame Single Collision Count
FMC = Frame Multiple Collisions Count
FC = Frame Collision Count
FDR = Frame Dropped Count
JF = Jumbo Frame Count

iSCSI Host   | Port    | F            | B               | MF     | BF     | PF   | CF     | FDF  | FED  | FLC  | FA   | FSC  | FMC  | FC   | FDR  | JF

Controller 0 |  port 0 | 440573739    | 651904980400    | 0      | 0      | 0    | 0      | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0
Controller 0 |  port 1 | 440549412    | 651892177000    | 0      | 0      | 0    | 0      | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0
Controller 1 |  port 0 | 109676946034 | 148467634266838 | 0      | 0      | 512  | 131072 | 512  | 1024 | 1024 | 1024 | 512  | 1792 | 2304 | 2304 | 589824
Controller 1 |  port 1 | 402653242    | 111669157090    | 524288 | 524288 | 2304 | 720896 | 2304 | 3328 | 3840 | 4352 | 2048 | 3584 | 5632 | 2048 | 1114112
```

My suspicion is that the network card utilized by Servers B and C doesn't have the capabilities needed to achieve the performance we are looking for (notice that the Jumbo Frame count is 0 -- Jumbo Frames being something I've seen recommended when multiple servers are accessing a single MD3000i controller). Server A accesses the MD3000i through a Broadcom BCM57085 NetXtreme II, while Servers B and C access the MD3000i through an Intel PRO/1000 MB Dual Port.

As of now, I don't have a firm method for isolating the cause of the slow read throughput on Controller 0 (Servers B and C).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the lack of jumbo frames is most likely the issue.

For a 1500 byte MTU frame, you'll probably have about 200-250 bytes of overhead between iSCSI, checksumming, TCP/IP, ethernet framing, et cetera. That leaves around 1250 bytes available for data transfer. On the other hand, a 9000 MTU jumbo frame can transmit around 7 times as much data with the same overhead.

You might also want to look to see if the cards have a TCP Offload Engine (TOE), and make sure they're enabled. That can have a decent impact on throughput, especially if CPU starts bottlenecking the process.